# Saving float number in SQLite issue?

Tags: sql, sqlite, floating-point, precision, rounding

I tried saving some floats into SQLite tables (for the first time) but the stored values are different from what I wanted to save. They were nearly exactly the numbers I saved. This requires me to round or truncate numbers when selecting using query or after filling into DataTable, which may cause the rounded result have a little difference from the actual saved version of the number.

For example, I tried saving this float number 7.64, but the actual saved value was 7.6399998664855957, the same for 6.1 (6.0999999046325684), 4.74 (4.7399997711181641), 5.76 (5.7600002288818359)...

Could you give me some solution for this? Rounding is not what I want, I just want to save exactly what user entering.

Thank you very much in advance!

## UPDATE

After some testing, I would like to add a note that the problem seems to happen only when I add new values to the table, after added, if I change the values (of course via my application), they are saved exactly what I entered. Here is the code for adding new item:

```
DataRow dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
dr["myFloatColumn"] = float.Parse(myTextBox.Text.Trim());
myDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
myDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which datatype you are using for that column.

Comment: of course, I used float type for that column. Thanks!

Comment: I created a  one column table in SQLite with float dataype, I also inserted some values like 6.1,4.74 etc. when I am browsing my table content with SQLite Database Browser, It is showing exactly which I  inserted. how did you find that SQLite is not storing exact value which you have entered.

Comment: What type of inserting have you used? If inserting directly via SQLite designer integrated in VS Studio, that's not what I did. I inserted values via DataTable, all the values are saved into DataTable first, then the Adapter updates theses values into SQLite tables. Thanks!

Comment: I insert values in table using "insert into" command.

Comment: If so, may the problem be caused by DataTable? I don't even think of that. Because I have used DataTable for a long time along with beginning programming database using ADO.NET, but I've only experienced it with SQL Server or MS Access and everything was OK. This is the first time I've used SQLite and I don't think it can be DataTable's fault. Thanks!

Comment: I have to add one thing that, I've tried saving a new value and it saved exactly what I input. But the wrong values were saved when I added them for the first time. I used float.Parse() to get the values from textboxes and assign these values for DataRow["columnName"], All these steps have been done very frequently and OK before when I worked with SQL Server or MS Access. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29299/discussion-between-vijendra-singh-and-king-king)

Comment: Please read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @CL the first link is too simple, the second is too long to read, it's a problem saving the float number which is not simple to understand at once. But why does it happen only when adding new item? After that, editing to any other will be OK, the remarkable point here is when adding I assign DataRow["floatColumn"] directly to float.Parse() while when saving, it's automatically assigned via the binding mechanism. My TextBox (for entering the float number) is bound to the float column in my DataGridView. You suggested a good link but not really answered my question, at the moment, rounding is OK